How to deal with a sabotaging co-worker?
I've been working in a wonderful multinational product-based company having a great employee friendly casual approach culture and currently reorganized with a new team. Since joining this team, I've encountered an extremely stringent performance measurement system that penalizes me for outcomes beyond my control due to policy constraints or a technical issue. I’ve politely voiced my concerns to my manager.
This week, things reached a breaking point. Another coworker, who is an individual contributor and not a manager, has been nitpicking things as quality check and labelling them as mistakes in my work. For example, I was penalized for addressing a person in an email by their preferred name (as listed in the company system) instead of their legal name, and for using a different font style in the email. These were escalated as mistakes and recorded negatively in performance metrics.
I am shocked because the company as a whole doesn’t operate this way, and this coworker's actions seem unnecessary and incompetent. The "preferred name versus legal name" issue is particularly outrageous and childish to an extent that if I escalate this as a concern then it would become a laughing and embarrassing matter for that coworker and the real team manager as it clearly displays the their lack of empathy or understanding of a real "QC Framework" as I am not working on Legal documents or the legal team where such details may be looked at. There are other similar instances feels very trivial in nature, I have had multiple opinions feeling the same this looks too far fetched and uneccessary.
How should I handle this situation? It’s causing me significant mental distress, I cannot ignore this as an incompetent or sabotaging co worker as at the end it is discrediting my genuine work and unjustly negatively impacting my Performance Measures on record. I’m looking for advice on how to proceed. Thank you.

Do theose KPIs impact anything? Your pay, your title, is there an evaulation at year's end or something?

The IC Manager is different to your Manager right? Have you spoken to your own Manager about this? What did they say?

Does this IC manager treat other team members the same way ? Talk to your team mates to find out.

"It’s causing me significant mental distress". There is absolutely no reason to let that happen to you. Some things he marked as errors in 1 single email would not have that much impact to your performance ratings.

The "IC manager" clearly isn't your direct manager, so why has anything they do or say impact on your KPIs? Why would something a random person says be part or your performance rating?

"... if I escalate this as a concern then it would become a laughing and embarrassing matter for that IC manager" -- This sounds like it would solve the problem. Any reason not to do so?

@circleback, Are you 100% sure that the IC manager specifically wrote that the use of italics in the email is the ONLY reason he marked your quote as an ERROR ? Did the IC manager actually indicated the use of italics is the ONLY reason ? -- If you are 100% sure, then the IC manager is mentally ill. But, if you are not 100% sure that the use italics is the ONLY reason, then it is a great idea to ask him why he marked your quote as an ERROR (Maybe, he may think that the quote does not apply to the scenario you mentioned in your email or there is some other explanation ?) .


For example, I was penalized for addressing a person in an email by their preferred name (as listed in the company system) instead of their legal name, and for using italics when quoting a company policy in the email body. These were marked as errors and negatively impacted my KPI.

If your manager (or supervisor, or anyone else in the team) has time to find "errors" like this, then they definitely do not have anything better to do, and you must ask yourself, do you also want to do the same when you reach their position?
I'd advise, find a new manager. Since you mentioned that this is not the culture of the overall organisation, you shall be able to find a new position with a new manager who will invest time in productive things rather than nitpicking. However, in the unlikely event of the previous consideration not holding true, that means finding a new job in another company - so be it.

I would add, Document, Document, and Document. Not for use now, but if they ever try to ding you on an actual performance review. Then you can push back hard. Also, please remember that no one can make someone "feel a certain way".  Yes-that is easier said than done. If you know that they are the person that isn't being normal, try to keep that in mind. It is your life and career, why should they get to derail either?

>   How should I handle this situation?
At least, give that IC manager a chance to explain his actions before concluding that he is toxic.
Have a meeting with the IC manager, and frame it as "I am interested in knowing how I can improve my writing to avoid these errors in the future because I am new in this team." This meeting may clear the air more than you expect.
In the meeting, ask him why it is an error to address him by his preferred name ?  (Maybe, he mistakenly does not know that his preferred name was entered in the company system as the "formal name".)
Ask him why he thinks that your quoting of a company policy in the email is an error. (Maybe, he thinks that this particular policy does not apply in this particular situation, and he probably meant to say you quoted the wrong policy ?)

Finally, are you sure that the things he marked as errors would negatively affect your performance rating ?
I doubt that some perceived errors by that IC manager in one email would drag your performance rating down drastically.
For most companies, the performances of employees are measured by many practical factors throughout the whole year.
For examples, as a software engineer, how many issues have you fixed per year ? How many software bugs have you created ? How many points do you get per sprint ? Do you deliver good products on time ? Are you a good leader of your team ? Do your teammates look up to you for help with difficult technical issues ? etc...

Who are you referring to when you say "him"?

@GregoryCurrie, "Him" is the IC manager.

I don't think the gender of the person is mentioned anywhere

@GregoryCurrie, I see your point.
